# CSS first-child doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I made this HTML:

```
<li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#curriculo">Currículo</a></li>
<li><a href="#trabalhos">Trabalhos</a></li>
<li><a href="#contato">Contato</a></li>
<li><a href="#sobre">Sobre</a></li>
```

And this CSS:

```
.nav ul li:first-child {
    padding-left: 11.8%;
    border-left: none;
 }
.nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px; 
    color: #6c6d6f;
    display: inline;
    border-left: 1px solid #3c948b;
    padding-left: 10%;
}
```

> | Home | CV | Trab | Contact | Sobre

But I can't remove the first `|` from the first child.  Can someone help me?

Comment: Open up inspect element an debug it for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
.nav ul li:first-child{padding-left: 11.8%; border-left:none;}
```

by

```
.nav ul li:first-child a{padding-left: 11.8%; border-left:none;}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/2rJ2m/3/)**

Comment: The order doesn't matter. The rule with the added `:first-child` is more specific.

Comment: @Quentin ok though so, I'll remove.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting `border-left: none` on the first `li` but you are setting `border-left:1px solid #3c948b` on all the `a` elements. Pick one element type or the other.